# Magento double cart

Tags: magento2, php, ecommerce-tracking

How to build a Magento double cart by sorting the vendors. one should normal process another one has added a product that is not available from this site. in detail, we build a site with multiple vendors product. if the buyer wants the product from other vendors products should add to the second cart.

Comment: You could use this extension https://cedcommerce.com/magento-2-extensions/marketplace/vendor-split-cart-addon

Comment: I already have some research on the split cart the problem with a split cart is its checkout on the same site(e-commerce site). how we check out the product if not available. I want to redirect to vendors site(or affiliate site). as I posted the question I want separate vendor's product into the second card and make checkout to vendor's site.